# Intellij IDEA compiles all modules even though I asked for only 1

Tags: intellij-idea

I have several modules in the project with a complex dependency structure. When I want to compile and run unit tests for 1 module, I want IDEA to ignore any compilation errors in unrelated modules. How can I do that? Currently IDEA compiles everything even if I say "compile module 1".

I don't want to setup several different projects for this.

Comment: Maybe you should use Maven to use goals.

Comment: We do use Gradle, but this would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

In the test Run configuration specify the corresponding module. IntelliJ IDEA will compile only this module and required dependencies, it will not try to compile other modules if this test module doesn't depend on them.

If for some reason it doesn't work as expected, please try to share a small sample to illustrate the problem.

Comment: If I select "Make" checkbox in the run config, it tries to make all project...if not, it doesn't do any compilation...it works only if classes are already compiled.

Comment: Did you specify the correct module that doesn't depend on other modules that do not compile? Can you share a sample project to reproduce the problem?

Comment: This question is 10 years old so is what came up when I was trying to Google it.  I'm sure there is amore official way, but I right clicked on the module in question and built it, then in the Run Config I clicked modify options and `Do not build before run`

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your dependencies. I had this same issue because the Ivy plug-in had added what it thought was a needed lib which contained a class that would not compile due to a missing dependency. Once I removed it, the build ran fine.